# Running java app in kubernetes container is not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubectl

I am trying to deploy and run the java application in kubernetes POD for which I am getting below error. 
But when I run it as a docker container it is running fine.

Here is the Dockerfile -

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ENV artifact mysessionmanager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
WORKDIR /root/apps
COPY . /root/apps
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["java -jar ${artifact}"]

docker build -t mysessionmanager .
docker tag mysessionmanager xxxx/mysessionmanager:v1
docker push xxxx/mysessionmanager
kubectl run mysessionmanager --image=xxxx/mysessionmanager:v1 --port=8080
kubectl expose deployment --type=NodePort --port=80 --target-port=8080 --name=mysessionmanager
```

`kubectl get deployments` showing my deployment Available status as 0

`kubectl get pods` showing my POD's status as CrashLoopBackOff

`kubectl get logs mysessionmanager-5654545f8-mvt5x` shows nothing

```
kubectl describe pod mysessionmanager-5654545f8-mvt5x

Reason: CrashLoopBackOff
Last State: Terminated
Reason: ContainerCannotRun
Message: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"java -jar mysessionmanager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

But when I directly run the docker image using below command it works fine.

```
docker run -it mysessionmanager
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Does your `docker push` command also have the `...:v1` tag?

Comment: Yes you were right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need top use BOTH cmd and entrypoint commands.

in my projects I create a small bash script that the java command is written inside.

that small script is running in my entry-point without any cmd configured.

Comment: Still same error... I removed CMD and modified ENTRYPOINT to ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", ${artifact}]

Comment: put your java command in some simple sh script : ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
and in the entrypoint : exec java -jar ....

Comment: No luck still same error.. added following in execscript.sh -> exec java -jar mysessionmanager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar                  And modified Dockerfile to ENTRYPOINT ["./execscript.sh"]

Comment: @aa Sounds like David is spot on, you are not using the image you think you are using.